# mi programa no ejecuta todas la funciones correctamente en c

Tags: c, funciones, compilar, menu, ejecutar

estoy haciendo un programa para un proyecto escolar, y este contiene un menú, pero  a la hora de elegir la función mainEmpleado() el programa solo imprime las primeras lineas de codigo pero lo demás no lo ejecuta, simplemente finaliza el programa y ya y no me arroja ningún error, y tengo que entregar mi codigo mañana, todas las demas funciones que llamo en main() si funcionan correctamente. Aclaro que mainEmpleado() no me arroja ningun error simplemente empieza a ejecutarla, y cuando llega al segundo print se detiene el programa, ya a partir de el gets (que también he intentado con scanf y no) no ejectura las instrucciones, que sería el ciclo while y la llamada a las otras funciones.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    system("COLOR 02");
    //bienvenida();
    menu();
    return 0;
}
int menu(){
    char sn='n';
    int opcion;
    do
    {
        printf("  ____ ___ _   _ _____ __  __    _  _____ ___ ____ \n");
    
        printf(" / ___|_ _| \\ | | ____|  \\/  |  / \\|_   _|_ _/ ___| \n");

        printf("| |    | ||  \\| |  _| | |\\/| | / _ \\ | |  | | |    \n");

        printf("| |___ | || |\\  | |___| |  | |/ ___ \\| |  | | |___ \n");

        printf(" \\____|___|_| \\_|_____|_|  |_/_/   \\_\\_| |___\\____|\n\n**************************************************************");

        printf("\nBienvenido al menú de opciones\n1) COMPRAR BOLETOS\n2) CONSULTAR BOLETOS COMPRADOS\n3) VER CARTELERA \n");
        printf("\n¿Introduzca el número de la acción que desea hacer? \n");
        scanf("%i", &opcion);

        switch(opcion){
        case 1: 
            comprarBoleto();
            contadorCierre(10);
            break;
        case 2:
            consultarUsuario();
            contadorCierre(10);
            break;
        case 3:
            consultarCartelera();
            printf("\n¿Desea volver al menu? (s/n)");
            scanf("%c", &sn);
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 4:
            mainEmpleado();
            contadorCierre(10);
            break;
        }
    } while (sn == 's');
    //return;
}
void mainEmpleado(){
    //sn = 's';
    system("cls");
    char iop, sbc;
    
    int conting = 0;
    printf("SI DESEA SUBIR UNA CARTELERA PRESIONE s \nSI DESEA DAR DE BAJA LA CARTELRA ACTUAL PRESIONES b \n"); 
    gets(&sbc);
    switch(sbc){
        case 's': system("cls");
            do{             
                subirPelicula(conting); 
                printf("%s\n","¿Desea ingresar una película? (s/n)");
                scanf("%s", &iop);
                conting++;
    
            }while(iop=='s');
            break;
        case 'b':
            eliminarCartelera();
            break;
    }

}   

void subirPelicula(int conter){

    char pelicula[100];
    char horario[100];
    char iop2;
    FILE *file; 
    FILE *arch;
    file = fopen("altaPeliculas.dat", "ab");
    arch = fopen("altaHorarios.dat", "ab");
    
    printf("%s\n","Ingrese el nombre de una película");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", &pelicula); 
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", pelicula);
    do{     
        printf("%s\n","Ingrese el Horario de la película separado por comas en el formato HH:MMpm o am");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]", &horario);
        //fprintf(arch, "%i\n%s\n",conter,horario);
        printf("%s\n","Desea subir otro horario?");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", &iop2 );        
    }while(iop2=='s');
        
    fclose(file);
    fclose(arch);
    return;
}   

void eliminarCartelera(){
    system("cls");;
    printf("eliminando archivo...");
    contadorCierre(4);
    sleep(3);
    remove("altaPeliculas.dat");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que declarar las funciones arriba de tu main, o declarar y definir las funciones arriba de tu main. Recuerda que el compilador lo lee de arriba para abajo, de entonces en tu main, aún no existe la función menú

Comment: `sbc` es un unico caracter. [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) toma un array de caracteres. Al escribir a `sbc` vas a parar escribiendo a memoria que no tienes asignada, cayendo en comportamiento indefinido. En ese punto es tan valido que tu programa funcione, como que no lo haga, como que lo haga algunas veces si y otras no, que lo mate el sistema operativo (que supongo sera este caso). Si caes en comportamiento indefinido todo vale.

Comment: Solucionarlo es sencillo. O lees unicamente un caracter usando [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar), o le das mas espacio a `sbc` para que pueda tomar varios caracteres, y usas unicamente el primero.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en la primer lectura del teclado (funcion menu), la funcion scanf no vacia por completo el buffer de teclado, para solucionarlo puedes usar inmediatamente despues del scanf() la intruccion while(getchar()!='\n'); . Lo que hace es ir tomando todo lo que dejo la funcion anterior en el buffer, caracter a caracter hasta que encuentra el retorno de carro (\n) y sale del while. No es la solucion mas elegante pero funciona. En la segunda lectura de teclado, el metodo gets, es una funcion un tanto peligrosa (puede desbordar la pila). Si es para un proyecto escolar, reemplazala de la misma forma que antes, primero el scanf y luego el while.